# Mixed Mode authentication for a webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I searched around a bit but could not find any answer that sounds like what I need.

I have a webservice used over the internet (Not only intranet). I want to create a login functionality that will allow users to either log in with their windows login or a custom username, password combination that I will store in my database. Is this possible?